# Exception in Sharepoint 2010 basic and enterprise search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am getting an exception in the Sharepoint logs as follows, 11/06/2012 13:44:27.34

> w3wp.exe (0x1584)                           0x2020  SharePoint Server
>   Search        Exceptions                      1hjo    Medium      Exception
>   thrown: 0x80131600
>   (d:\office\source\search\native\ytrip\tripoli\icommand\qpcache.cxx:1444
>   ip 0x000007FECDE3DB23)    65bd4b50-7216-4414-910f-b4

How to resolve this Exception thrown: 0x80131600 ?

Comment: what was you trying to do

Comment: I was trying to search some documents.

Answer (score 0):

Seen this error before when the search service is having problems initializing, best workaround is just to rebuild/reprovision search.

You can move it around: http://iedaddy.com/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-migrating-search-admin-to-different-servers-in-the-farm/

But make sure that wherever you move the query component that the app pool is running under a network domain account and not networks services.

Also try giving the app pool local admin to rule out the various permissions issues.  Generally this issue crops up on a migrated farm, so you might want to rerun the psconfig to repair permissions as well.